# Application Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

This code shows an error :

```
private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment;
    switch (position)
    {
        case 1:
            fragment = new PizzaFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PastaFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new StoresFragment();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new TopFragment();
    }

    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();

}
```

when I initialize fragment with new PizzaFragment or PastaFragment, android studio shows an error "Incompatible types"

Comment: what is  error log ?

Comment: We need to know `WHAT ERROR IT THROWS` in order to solve it

Comment: Make sure your fragments PizzaFragment and PastaFragment are extending Fragment.

Comment: make sure you are implementing `android.app.Fragment` or `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. And Same with FramgnetManager and `FragmentTransition`

Comment: Be sure to consistently use classes from the support library **or** native classes. **Do not mix them.**

Comment: Please show the entire error and tell us which line it is on.

Comment: check all fragment import same package `package android.support.v4.app;`

Comment: @Bharat : Please make sure you have imported same `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` class in every Fragment. It will work fine after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create object of that fragment .It will work.

```
switch (position)
{
    case 1:
       PizzaFragment fragment = new PizzaFragment();
       // apply FragmentTransaction
        break;
    case 2:
       PastaFragment fragment = new PastaFragment();
       // apply FragmentTransaction
        break;
    case 3:
        StoresFragment fragment = new StoresFragment();
        // apply FragmentTransaction
        break;
    default:
       TopFragment  fragment = new TopFragment();
      // apply FragmentTransaction
}
```

Comment: That is not Proper way to do. Because you have to write same code multiple time. The way @Bharat Khadodra implemented was proper, But there was only type compatibility issue.

Comment: For this case all fragments are not extends Fragment . That case we have no option for that.He extends ListFragment.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same once and the mistake was that the `PizzaFragment` and `PastatFragent` classes were not extending the Fragment, just look at that for once

**Like**

`PizzaFragment extends Fragment{`

and

`PastaFragment extends Fragment{`

**And Maybe**
you are importing different packages,so check your import statements

Comment: but my PizzaFragment class is extending ListFragment and not the Fragment.